# Identify only when value matches

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to return only rows that have the match e.g Value = A, but I only need the rows that have A and with no other values.

T1:

```
ID   Value    
1     A     
1     B     
1     C     
2     A     
3     A    
3     B    
4     A    
5     B    
5     D    
5     E   
5     F
```

Desired Output:

```
2   
4
```

how can I achieve this? 
when I try the following, 1&3 are also returned:

```
 select ID from T1 where Value ='A'
```

Comment: Match WHAT??? Please explain.

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "have the match".

Comment: "1&3 are also returned"... Of course they are, because they also have value A. Why do you expect that only 2 and 4 should be returned? What extra rule are you applying to get that result? Do you mean to only return numbers which don't also have another row with another value? Please make your logic explicit.

Comment: I need only the rows that have A, and do not have any other values.

Comment: Individual **rows** only ever have one value anyway, so that statement doesn't clarify anything. Do you mean the **numbers** which only occur in a single row whose value is A?

Comment: yes. Only IDs with one row and value = A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.id
from tablename t
where t.value = 'A'
and not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where id = t.id and value <> 'A'
)
```

From the sample data you posted there is no need to use:

```
select distinct t.id
```

but if you get duplicates then use it.
Another way if there are no null values:

```
select id
from tablename
group by id
having sum(case when value <> 'A' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Or if you want the rows where the id has only 1 value = 'A':

```
select id
from tablename
group by id
having count(*) = 1 and max(value) = 'A'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way is aggregation with `having`:

```
select id
from tablename
group by id
having min(value) = max(value) and
       min(value) = 'A';
```

Note that this ignores `NULL` values so it could return `id`s with both `NULL` and `A`.  If you want to avoid that:

```
select id
from tablename
group by id
having count(value) = count(*) and
       min(value) = max(value) and
       min(value) = 'A';
```

Comment: Plus one for explicitly asking about `null` and showing how it could be handled.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( ID, Value ) AS
SELECT 1, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'F' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT ID
FROM   test_data
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT( CASE Value WHEN 'A' THEN 1 END ) = 1
AND    COUNT( CASE Value WHEN 'A' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END ) = 0
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | ID |
> | -: |
> |  2 |
> |  4 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=99d205521a911942a4042bfe8a14110e)*